# How do I make a jetpack in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to make a jetpack, in Unity, but I have a little problem. I can't make good flying controller.

There are two input options:

1. Control flying using a keyboard, and control movement using a vector, while always moving forward.
2. Control flying and movement using a keyboard, only.

Here's what I have planned, so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class JetScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fuel = 60.0f;
    public float fuelUsing = 4.0f;
    public float maxFuel = 300.0f;
    public float gravity = 10.0f;
    public float JetForce = 5.0f;
    public float FlyingTime = 10000f;
    public Camera _camera;

    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;

        if ((fuel >= 0) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C)) && (FlyingTime >= 0))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(
                    new Vector3(_camera.transform.forward.x,  /* what goes here? */, 
                    _camera.transform.forward.z), ForceMode.VelocityChange);

            FlyingTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(
                new Vector3(0, -gravity * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass, 0));
    }
}
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: Please add more detail about 1. how exactly you want the character to behave and 2. how it behaves instead with the code you posted.

Comment: My player flying forward and don't rotates. It will change flying vector after my player will ground and blast off

Comment: Is that how it currently works or how you would like it to work? We can not help you when you don't clearly describe your problem.

Comment: No , I want that my player will fly to where looks , Now It don't rotate where my player is watching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things I notice when examining your code:

1. You get the rigidbody component twice every physics step (FixedUpdate).
2. Your implementation of gravity.
3. Difficulty calculating JetPack Force Direction.

Assuming you have a good reason for handling gravity on your own rather than letting the physics engine apply it, here are some tips:

**Problem 1: Getting a component**

In your start function, assign the rigidbody to a class variable. aka:

```
private Rigidbody rigid;
//...    
void Start() {
    rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
    rigid.freezeRotation = true;
    rigid.useGravity = false;
    //etc
}
```

By doing so, your class only needs to get a reference to Rigidbody when it starts up. You can use rigid anywhere else without needing to have your script find it again. Conversely, you can make the rigid variable public and drag in the rigidbody component yourself from the inspector. This method wont require you to use GetComponent at all.

**Problem 2: Gravity Implementation**

The first red flag I see is that you are applying gravity * mass for your downward force. *This is incorrect* when mimicking real world physics. Google "Bowling ball vs feather" for reference. You should only apply the force of gravity, regardless of object mass.

**Problem 3: Jetpack direction**

Handling force and direction in a single vector can be difficult to comprehend at first. I calculate the force vector to apply by multiplying the force (JetForce) by the direction vector. In your case, the following code should help:

```
Vector3 forceToApply = JetForce * _camera.transform.up
rigid.AddForce(forceToApply, ForceMode.VelocityChange)
```

This hopefully will set you in the right direction for building your very first jetpack controller. I did not address smoothing out movement. For these tasks, you may want to consider a different [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html), along with clamping the velocity at a maximum speed. For the best results, I find that calculating a desiredVelocity and then using [Vector3.SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) to smoothly achieve it is very effective. Select the method that is best for your game, whatever it may be!

Comment: I watched  "Bowling ball vs feather" video , I understood that I know physics very bad :c

Comment: I'm no expert either, which is why I'm glad Unity has rigidbodies and gravity built in!